# Error when reading data from RDS (mysql) in Next.js

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js

I just started using Next.js. So I don't know what to know. I am working on reading data from RDS using mysql2/promise. A line is read from the table and reflected well on the screen. However, from two rows, the data is broken. Another problem is that even if one line is read successfully, if the length of text in one column becomes long, the data is broken. I really don't know what caused it.

What do I need to look out for and fix?

lib/db.js

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

export async function LibDB(query, values) {
    const DbConnection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
    });

    try {
        const [results] = await DbConnection.execute(query, values)
        DbConnection.end();
        return results

    } catch (error) {
        throw Error(error.message);

    }

}
```

pages/api/get_result.js

```
import{LibDB} from "../../lib/db"

export default async function handler(req, res) {

    try {

        const query = "SELECT T.test_id, T.test_share, R.test_title, R.result_title, R.result_name, R.result_description, R.result_sub_description, R.result_image, R.result_image_kakao, R.result_image_facebook FROM tests_results R INNER JOIN logs L ON L.test_id = R.test_id AND L.result_type = R.result_type INNER JOIN tests T ON R.test_id = T.test_id WHERE L.log_id = ? AND L.test_id = ?";
        const value = [req.query.logId, req.query.testId];
        const data = await LibDB(query,value);

        // res.status(200).json({results: data})
        res.status(200).send(data);

    } catch (error) {

        res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
        res.status(500).send('error')
    }

}
```

result_description colume.

When the text length of this column is short, it fully reflects one line. However, if the text length increases, the data that just came out well cannot be imported. I think the standard is 150 characters or less. It was the same even if I modified the table and maximized the varchar length.

call api

```
export async function getServerSideProps({params}){
    const response = await axios.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL+"/api/get_result", {params: {logId: params.id, testId:1}})
        const data =response.data
        return {
            props:{resultData: data}
        };
}
```

I looked to see if there were any values ​​that interfered with the JSON format, but there was no such part. I found out that I couldn't read it because of the length of the text while changing the length of the text in the column little by little.